# Properties created by the Storyboard in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have a UIViewController in storyboard and I have it create the code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView2;
```

However, after my `viewDidLoad` method, I print out `self.webView2`, and it is `(null)`. Why is it null? I need to add a URL to the webView, but it's null at this point.

Comment: In Interface Builder, you have to link the web view to your outlet. You do this by control dragging (or right-click-dragging from the web view to) from the web view to your `IBOutlet`. See [Configuring the View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html) in the Apple's _Your First iOS App_ tutorial. Frankly, it probably makes sense for you to go through that tutorial before doing your own app.

Comment: Did you check that the outlet is actually connected? Right click on the view controller and check connections. Or the webview. Or look at the little circle next to this property declaration and see that it is filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you drag and connect the UIWebView to the outlet in the storyboard (Is the circle in front  of the property filled in)?  That will automatically instantiate the control.

Comment: The circle is not filled in. How do I get it filled in?

Comment: oh...I changed the name. is this not allowed?

Comment: Control-drag from the UIWebView to the yellow circle (view controller) at the bottom. Select the property name from the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the property in code doesn't create the outlet. You have to have *two* things: the property in the code, and the outlet in the storyboard. Make sure you actually have an outlet from the UIViewController in the storyboard to the UIWebView in its view.

It might help you to read the section about outlets in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_outlet_connections

This section of the book talks about "nibs" but applies equally to "storyboards".

Comment: I didn't create the property myself via typing code. I right clicked and dragged it.